# cursorX is not defined(..)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get cursorX coordinate from modal generated by jQuery BlockUI plugin.
when I try to do so with below code it gives "cursorX is not defined(..)" error.

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){
        cursorX = e.pageX;
        cursorY = e.pageY;console.log('dsahg');
    }
cursorX;
```

Comment: can you post you code logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its not defined .you need define with `var` like this

```js
console.log(cursorX);//see this its a undefined .its not defined by anything before

var cursorX=""; // default value is empty 
var cursorY ="" // default value is empty 
document.onmousemove = function(e){
        cursorX = e.pageX;
        cursorY = e.pageY;console.log(cursorX);
    }
console.log(cursorX); //its a defined one .but pass the default empty value.Beacuse its show with window load .not after the mouse move
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access cursorX which is not defined before, You will be getting a reference error because there is no memory assigned for the variable.

```
cursorX;
```

> Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving declarations to
>   the top.

Javascript normally looks for all `var variable_name;` at first and assign a memory address to it. This is called [**javaScript Hoisting**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)

If you are not using [**Strict Mode**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp) and trying to assign a value then javaScript is forgiving and it will assign a memory for you and store the value.

You can check that you will have access to `clientX` after the reference error if you move your mouse cause javscript will create a memory for you.

Here,

```
function(e){
        cursorX = e.pageX;
        cursorY = e.pageY;console.log('dsahg');
}
```

Your problem here is that cursorX will be defined inside the `mousemove` but you are trying to access it before any mousemove.

**Obvious Solution is to define it before using it.**

`var cursorX, cursorY;` outside the function even if it defined at the end of the file will work;

```js
// This will work but will give undefined error cause nothing is assigned to cursorX yet.
console.log(cursorX);

var cursorX = 0, cursorY = 0;

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  cursorX = e.pageX;
  cursorY = e.pageY;
  console.log(cursorX);
}
console.log(cursorX); //This will print 0 as by now we have assigned a value to it.

//var cursorX,cursorY; This will also work due to variable hoisting
```